# Maven for deployement for a client/server app?

Tags: maven, client-server, maven-3, legacy-code

We're currently moving from a quite old Perl + Ant build system to maven.

The software itself is a client/server app using RMI as main communication system and the build produces a (large) number of jars.

This piece of software existed long before usual frameworks become mature, so the *it does not* make usage of :

- any usual persistence layers (Hibernate/JPA like)
- any MVC application frameworks like Spring
- any Java EE infrastructure ( no war/ear packaging)

In fact it is shipped as a set of jar and conf files, with a set of startup/admin scripts.

We ported the compilation/building system to maven3. The client and server deployment trees are currently being ported to maven with the assembly plug-in.

What we're currently missing, in the maven framework, is to be able to deploy the app on development stations and build servers and to run some basic integration tests.

Ideally we'd like to use maven in to deploy an image of the client, server and a DB fixture ( that is actually code generated as well).

I've found a lot of pointers on how to deploy a web app, few on the integration tests themselves, and almost none on how to handle the deployment of a (very) old school C/S architecture using maven.

So my questions would be:

- are there are any known and mature plug-ins capable of deploying the app. and handling the DB fixture in a C/S manner?

If not, what would be your advice(s):

- use ant rules and bind them to maven life cycle in order to handle the deployment process (we have a couple of ant targets that could be adapted to fit in the process)?
- write a maven plug-in that would fit the exact deployment needs?

Comment: What kind of client/server things do you have that you have to use assembly-plugin (no things like EJB/WAR ?)

Comment: What kind of integration tests do you like to run? There exists the maven-failsafe-plugin to run integration tests? The question is: Is it not sufficient or do you have particular requirements? Deployment to app servers (JBoss, Glassfish etc.) can be done by using cargo-maven plugin or JBoss (i don't know the name).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Some info : the app is basically a set of jars and a couple of launch scripts, there are no J2EE elements (EJB, Wars), while most of the maven deployement plugins address J2EE infrastructures. The integration tests can be coded and runned from separate modules, however I'm more looking for a "maven way" of deploying a legacy code C/S application with an empty database ( I know sql maven plugin can help up to some point).

Comment: That sounds like a case doing the deployment with Ant scripts and only the build and packaging part with Maven. Unfortunately for such a special there do not exist any particular maven plugins.

Comment: This is what I was initially planning. Thanks again for the info.